# ifstream loop to only read when "=" is found

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm fairly new to C++. I'm creating a program that uses multiple .dat input files. In these input files `<double>`, `<int>`, `<char>` and `<bool>` variable definitions are stored. Variables are declared within the program itself. I want the input files to be somewhat user friendly, therefore I added text to clarify.

I'm using ifstream with overload parameter `>>` to read the input files. To ignore redundant text I'm using `.ignore(256, '\n')` and to find a variable definition `.ignore(256, '=')`.

The code I'm using works, but it looks ridiculous. How can I improve this code to just read all the lines with a `=` symbol?

Below a representation of what I'm doing right now. I chose .dat for input because I'm using .txt for output. It just makes the files a bit more recognizable, but I don't mind changing to .txt if necessary.

**inputfile.dat**

```
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
var1    = 1     2       3
var2    = 4.5   5.5     6.5
var3    = 7     8.5     9
...
varX    = 10.0  11  12.0
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
var4    = 99
var5    = B
var6    = 0
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
IGNORE THIS LINE
v = 0
longvarname = 100
var whitespace = 0
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main (){

std::ifstream myfile1 ("inputfile.dat");
if (myfile1.is_open()){
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> var1_1 >> var1_2 >> var1_3;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> var2_1 >> var2_2 >> var2_3;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> var3_1 >> var3_2 >> var3_3;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    ...
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> varX_1 >> varX_2 >> varX_3;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> var4;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> var5;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');    
    myfile1 >> var6;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '\n');
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> v; 
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> longvarname;
    myfile1.ignore(256, '=');
    myfile1 >> var_whitespace;
}
else{
    std::cerr << "ERROR! No access to inputfile.dat. Press ENTER to exit." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    exit(1);
}
return 0
}
```

I've tried looking into `getline()` and splitting the line but I don't fully understand that. I don't want `"strings"` because all my variables are anything but a string (apart from one `<char>`).

Comment: I am thinking that some research into parser practices might be in order. If the file format for the input is under your control, consider using a standard format and getting a library that supports it... XML, YML, JSON, INI are a few that are out there.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```cpp
std::string line;
std::getline(myfile1, line); // note: give myfile1 a more descriptive name
                             // easier-to-read code is easier-to-debug as well
std::istringstream tokenizer(line);
std::string key;
std::string value;
if (std::getline(tokenizer, key, '=') && std::getline(tokenizer, value)
{
    // use key and value
    // key and value will be raw string data, whitespace and all, and 
    // will certainly require some amount of massaging into a more usable
    // form. Remy raises the point of trimming the whitespace in the comments
    // and in this case the string of nymbers will likely need to be 
    // transformed into a vector of an actual numeric type.
}
```

Wrap this up into a function and call the function in a loop to consume the file.

Comment: Just note that using this approach with the example data shown, `key` will end up with trailing whitespace that you will have to strip off manually, and `value` will contain ALL of the values instead of separating them. You might consider using `>>` instead of `getline()`, eg: `string key, value; char delim; if ((tokenizer >> key >> delim) && (delim == '=')) { while (tokenizer >> value) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

I would scan this file line by line into a string.
Then try to see if that line contains a `=` in the line.

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(myfile1), line)
{
    if (line.find('=') != std::string::npos) {
        handleImportant(line);
    }
}
```

Now what you do with the line depends on your file definition.
It is not clear what your file definition is from the question.

Some lines have numbers, some have a set of numbers and one seems to have a character. It is unclear what is expected of the shown variables are the only variables.

But if we assume the simplist format:

```
<Variable Name> = <Some Text>
```

Then for each variable. We can store the associated text. We can split the text using a string stream.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>   variableMap;
void handleImportant(std::string const& line)
{
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    std::string variable;
    char        assign = 'X';

    if (lineStream >> variable >> assign && assign == '=') {

         // The rest of the line
         // Or you can try and break up the line and convert
         // to a specific type.
         std::string restOfLine;
         std::getline(lineStream, restOfLine);

         variableMap[variable] = restOfLine;
    }
}
```